# Different distance between bars in clustered Power BI bar chart

Tags: powerbi

I came across this unusual problem. I try to create chart showing top 1 manager(Y axis) by rating (X axis) from each region, with Region added to legend for color differentiation. However, then bars are located on uneven distance from each other, some are closer, other are further from the next one. (picture 1)
Issue seems to go away if I add Region to Y axis above Manager's Name, but then Y axis shows region labels (picture 2), and not managers names. if it's added below or removed, bars go haywire again.

[image: various distance between bars]

[image: uniform distance between bars]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and think it's because PBI is trying to display all the categories from the Legend on the Y axis, which show up as "hidden" or blank bars in between your other bars and make it look like the spacing is random. I was able to fix this by switching from a Clustered Bar to a Stacked Bar chart. Couldn't figure out how to suppress those other legend categories from the Y axis in a Clustered Bar. Hope that helps.